# Wordpress - do not have sufficient permissions for cloned databases

Tags: php, database, wordpress, sandbox

I'm setting up a duplicate sandbox wordpress CMS for a website, and when I log into Wordpress I'm getting "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

Here's what I did:

1. Created subdomain sandbox.mysite.com
2. Downloaded all existing WP files and uploaded them to sandbox
3. Copied all WP database tables and renamed all prefixes `new_` from `wp_`
4. wp-config.php, changed `$table_prefix` to `new_` from `wp_`
5. In table `new_options`, I changed the rows `siteurl` and `home` to `sandbox.mysite.com`

Logging in here gives me the error.

Without changing the `$table_prefix` variable in wp-config.php, I can log in, but it's using the original database and redirects to the original wordpress.
It's getting all the info from the original tables this way.

I can't find what else I need to change, not sure if it's a user permission or a pathing issue or what. Any help is great appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here, I solved it, and I'm now up and running. I originally did everything right, but after some more research I found that I was missing an update in the table `new_options`. I needed to also update the column `option_name`. I found this by searching for all instances of the old prefix in that table using

```
SELECT * FROM  `new_options` WHERE  `option_name` LIKE  '%wp_%'LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This article helped me:
https://digwp.com/2010/10/change-database-prefix/